# \cmidrule one column wide

Tags: tables, booktabs

What's the problem with a `\cmidrule(lr){1}`?

Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{rcccccc}
\hline
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Something} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Something} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
Median & 
      1 & 
      1 & 
      0 & 
      1 & 
      2 & 
      3 \\
\cmidrule(lr){1} % <---- Here the issue
SD &
      70.4 & 
      2.5 & 
      1.71 & 
      57.61 & 
      114.53 & 
      308.42 \\
N & 
      15481 & 
      118 & 
      30 & 
      15481 & 
      118 & 
       30 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`\cmidrule` needs a start *and* an end column number even if they are the same. That's why you have to use

```
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
```

if only the first column should be underlined.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{rcccccc}
\hline
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Something} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Something} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
Median & 
      1 & 
      1 & 
      0 & 
      1 & 
      2 & 
      3 \\
\midrule(lr){1-1} % <---- changed
SD &
      70.4 & 
      2.5 & 
      1.71 & 
      57.61 & 
      114.53 & 
      308.42 \\
N & 
      15481 & 
      118 & 
      30 & 
      15481 & 
      118 & 
       30 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```