Table causing compiling issues
I have this text and it seems to be causing me issues with the compiler. I have a similar table that complies just fine so i'm not sure what the issue may be.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm, }
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0.5em} % provide space between caption and top rule


    \begin{table}[hbt!]
        \centering
            \caption{Gum performance metrics}
        \label{tab:GUMPerformance-*}
        \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc} \toprule
     Chewing cycles& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Delta E_{00}^*$}&& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\Delta E_{76}^*$}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$e$}\\ 
        \cmidrule(lr){2}
        \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
        \cmidrule(lr){6}
        
             &  Actual & & Measured &  Actual\\ 
             \midrule
             10 & 4.26 &  & 19.25 & 14.15& 36.04 \\  
             20 & 6.55 &  & 28.25 & 23.98 &17.8\\ 
             30 & 8.59 &  & 43.40 & 35.35 &22.77\\ 
             40 & 7.88 & & 57.68 & 45.58 &26.55\\ 
             \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}


Please always include a small, but compilable test document in your question wgich includes a class and all the necessary packages.

sorry I'm not sure how where to put it but are you referring to this: \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
total={170mm,257mm},
left=20mm,
top=20mm, }
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0.5em} % provide space between caption and top rule

I guess  it's the \cmidrule{lr}{2}  (or 6) that causes the problem. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191718/cmidrule-one-column-wide

@Nenn Please put this in your question. You can see that code does not work well in comments.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, this solved the problem. Thank you!

If you'd now add the missing document environment to your question, you would have a good question!

Welcome. // Where did your \begin{document} ... \end{documet} environment go to ... ? See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure .


the number of specified columns and actual columns does not match

the syntax is \cmidrule(lr){n-m} with n the start column and m the end column.


--
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
    \centering
        \caption{Gum performance metrics}
    \label{tab:GUMPerformance-*}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc} 
    \toprule
 Chewing cycles& $\Delta E_{00}^*$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\Delta E_{76}^*$}& $e$\\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
         &  Actual & Measured &  Actual\\ 
         \midrule
         10 & 4.26 & 19.25 & 14.15& 36.04 \\  
         20 & 6.55 & 28.25 & 23.98 &17.8\\ 
         30 & 8.59 & 43.40 & 35.35 &22.77\\ 
         40 & 7.88 & 57.68 & 45.58 &26.55\\ 
         \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}

